# AWS CognitoID VS AWS Session Token

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm a bit confused about the difference between an AWS session token and an AWS CognitoID, are they they same? because through this code

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                      initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      identityPoolId:@"my-identity-pool"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSUnknown credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

[[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    else {
        // the task result will contain the identity id
        NSString *cognitoId = task.result;
       // -------------------Outputs cognito Id------------------------
        NSLog(@"%@,", task.result);

    }
    return nil;
}];
```

task.result gives back an AWS CognitoID but what about an AWS Session Token? How can I get it from my ios?

Comment: As Yosuke explained, you shouldn't need the session token/credentials if you're using the AWS Mobile SDK. However, can you please explain why you need or thought needed the session token?

Comment: So I was looking into an open source project which had their own backend or Developer Authentication and through a request to their API they sent back a session token  so I was trying to figure out how to replicate it since I'm using Parse as my backend but I was still iffy on the AWS concepts since when first starting out there seemed to be so many different keys and identification needed that everything became such a blur and hard to distinguish but now I realize there's just a few and I'm starting to understand the difference - hopefully this makes sense haha

Comment: after some more looking into the code, I realize they're  using AWSCredentialsProvider protocol which I believe requires accessKey, secretKey, and the sessionKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Cognito `IdentityId` is not the same as AWS temporary credentials. AWS temporary credentials consist of `accessKey`, `secretKey`, and `sessionKey`. `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` has properties with these names. See the [API doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html) for more details.

In general, if you are using any AWS service clients in the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS, you do not need to retrieve the AWS temporary credentials manually. The SDK automatically retrieves them when it needs them.